# Why does my state variable in ReactJS not render and why is it undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, state, render

Beginner to React and JavaScript, so forgive me if this is a simple fix.

I'm fetching data from a server and intend on parsing the response and storing elements of the response in an array which is a state variable, as I want to use variations in the state to update the page accordingly.

The issue I am having is that while using fetch(), I am able to retrieve the data from the server, but apparently I am unable to use setState() properly to assign the data to the variable. I've read that setState() is asynchronous, so your state variable might not be updated right away, and in that case I wonder if I can render the application whenever my state variable (array) is updated.

Below is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component{
  constructor(props)  {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      apiResponse: []
    }; 
    this.getData = this.getData.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData();
  }

  getData = () => {
    fetch('http://localhost:5000')
      .then(results => results.json())
      .then(console.log)
      .then(results => this.setState({apiResponse: results}, () => {
        console.log('data in state', this.state.apiResponse)
      }))
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
  }
  render()  {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Display</h1>
        <h1>{this.state.apiResponse}</h1>
        <h1>Does this work?</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The first console.log that I run after fetch returns the appropriate JSON object, however the next console.log after returns an undefined, and `{this.state.apiResponse}` does not render anything.

Comment: remove `.then(console.log)`

Comment: Can you display what you are getting from server?

Comment: @panditmonium and what you want to display in UI?

Comment: @panditmonium for each array you need to call `map`. `{this.state.apiResponse && this.state.apiResponse.map(apiRep => <div>{apiRep.recordsets.map(recordSet => <span>{recordSet.FactoryName}</span>)}</div>)}`. Cannot check if all {} () are OK right now

Comment: I want it so that I can display all the elements that belong in the [0] index of recordsets. From there, I will be parsing the JSON to retrieve just some of the variables ("E10StateName" for one)

Comment: {this.state.apiResponse && {this.state.apiResponse.map(singleResponse => {
singleResponse.map(singleElement => {
<span>{singleElement.FactoryName}</span>

})

})}}

Comment: @Apostolos, any clue why I get "this.state.apiResponse.map is not a function"? I tried your bit of code, and it compiled, however I got this TypeError.

Comment: @SijuSamson, I tried your response, however I believe there is an error where "{this.state.apiResponse && {this.state.apiResponse..." the code breaks at {this.state.apiResponse...}

Comment: wasn't sure what apiResponse held. you must iterate `recordSets` then. `{this.state.apiResponse && this.state.apiResponse.recordsets.map(recordSet => <span>{recordSet.FactoryName}</span>)}`

Comment: @panditmonium, I have posted my answer, please have a look at it. I am sure it will solve the issue

Comment: @Apostolos, so I tried that, and initially it said "cannot read property map of undefined", however I changed the first part of the statement to {this.state.apiResponse.recordsets && ...} and it compiled, however with a warning that "Each child in a list should have a unique key prop"..., I'm starting to think that to avoid confusion, I should change my query to something a lot simpler to work with!

Comment: If you want to remove that warning ( which i recommend you should), use keys within the loop. It will help React during the time of rendering.

Comment: that's normal. see react docs about `key` in iteration. just declare a property in your <span> tag using e.g. something unique from your object (an id for example)

Comment: Thank you for your help @Apostolos! I'm very new to this tech, but you have been very kind and helpful to bring me up to here.
When I used your statement, nothing was rendered (aside from the display and does this work statements), do you think this is still a key issue or is there something else going on?

Comment: i guess now you will need to ask a new question with a codesandbox preferably in order for us to test it and help you better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are handling the json object with `then` method but then you don't return something in order for the next `then` to have as input.

If you remove this line

```
.then(console.log)
```

then it should work.

Comment: Hey apostolos, 

Thank you for your response! I have tried your solution, and I was wondering if this means I'm along the right path...

I get an error message which says that the "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

Do you have any suggestions how I can workaround this issue? Thank you once again for your response!

Comment: if it is an array, you can use map function.

Comment: @panditmonium you need to handle accordingly your `this.state.apiResponse`. if it is not a string, a number, it cannot just be displayed with `{this.state.apiResponse}`. check `map` method

Comment: e.g. `{this.state.apiResponse.map(obj => <span>{obj.SOME_PROPERTY}</span>)}`

Comment: so I tried the following...
{apiResponse.map(apiRep => {apiRep.recordsets})}

This yielded that "apiResponse" was not defined...any suggestions?

Comment: `{this.state.apiResponse` not just `{apiResponse`. Also better is this `{this.state.apiResponse && this.state.apiResponse.map(apiRep => {apiRep.recordsets})}`

Comment: if `recordsets` is an object/array, then you need again to call `map` method, though.

Comment: Apostolos,
I tried your solution, and I suppose we encountered another error here. I have {this.state.apiResponse && this.state.apiResponse.map(apiRep => {apiRep.recordsets})}, and what I receive is an error about "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression no-unused-expressions". Any suggestions? Sir/madam, you have been very helpful, thank you!

EDIT: recordsets is indeed another array, where the 0 index has [x # of] objects.

Comment: `{this.state.apiResponse && this.state.apiResponse.map(apiRep => <span>{apiRep.recordsets}</span>)}`. Please check my previous comment too. if recordsets is object/array then you need once again to call map function. Also don't forget to accept an answer for your question to be considered "answered". its the green tick.

Comment: sorry i don't see any links. you could update your question with these links. if you quickly want to see that it is running, you could try this `{this.state.apiResponse && this.state.apiResponse.map(apiRep => <span>{JSON.stringify(apiRep.recordsets)}</span>)}`. It's the green tick near the answer, at the left side. Welcome to SO :)

Comment: @Apostolos, I updated the last discussion post, and the post with the link, and I marked your answer. I tried using stringify as well, however it still returns that this.state.apiResponse.map is not a function :/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is when you pass as callback to the `then` `consol.log` function and after what you continue with the `then` chaining and expect to have access to the result, what you should do by the way is call directly the `then` chain in which you set the `state` before call to `console.log` and then return `results` in that callback like this

```
fetch('http://localhost:5000')
  .then(results => results.json()) 
  .then(results => {
      this.setState({apiResponse: results}, () => {
          console.log('data in state', this.state.apiResponse)
      });
      return result;
   })
   .then(console.log);
```

Or just replace it with a normal function like this

```
fetch('http://localhost:5000')
  .then(results => results.json())
  .then((results) => {
      console.log(results);
      return results;
  })
  .then(results => {
      this.setState({apiResponse: results}, () => {
          console.log('data in state', this.state.apiResponse)
      });
      return result;
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

whenever you resolve a Promise using .then() you want to pass resolve to the next callback.
`.then(console.log)` breaks that. You don't have the results in your next callback.
Read more about that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) .

Answer (score 0):

It's problem in your **Chaining**, Here's a answer:

> The then method returns a Promise which allows for method chaining.
>
> If the function passed as handler to then returns a Promise, an
> equivalent Promise will be exposed to the subsequent then in the
> method chain.  - MDN

```js
...
      .then(console.log) // here you're not exposing any response
...
  }
```

A remedy could be:

```js
...
getData = () => {
    fetch('http://localhost:5000')
      .then(results => {console.log(results); return results.json()})
      .then(results => this.setState({apiResponse: results}, () => {
        console.log('data in state', this.state.apiResponse)
      }))
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
  }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import './App.css';
    
    class App extends Component{
      constructor(props)  {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
          apiResponse: []
        }; 
        this.getData = this.getData.bind(this);
      }
      componentDidMount() {
        this.getData();
      }
    
      getData = () => {
        fetch('http://localhost:5000')
          .then(results => results.json())
          .then(console.log)
          .then(results => this.setState({apiResponse: results}))
          .catch(err => console.error(err));
      }
      render()  {
        return (
          <div className="App">
            <h1>Display</h1>
            <h1>{this.state.apiResponse && 
         this.state.apiResponse.recordSets.map((singleRecord, index)=>           
  singleRecord.map(singleElement => <span> 
              {singleElement.FactoryName}</span>))}</h1>
                <h1>Does this work?</h1>
              </div>
            );
      }
    }
    
    export default App;
```

Comment: This is the error I get...
Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression no-unused-expression

Comment: @panditmonium, I have updated my answer, and tested too. It will resolve the issue.

Comment: hey, I tried your code with a small fix (had to switch this.state.apiResponse && ... to this.state.apiResponse.recordsets && ...) and it worked! Thank you for your help and support!!

Comment: Glad it helped.